# git does not ignore directory even though it is in .gitignore file

Tags: git, gitignore

`git status` prints the following:

```
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    new file:   .gitignore
    new file:   app.js
    new file:   dev1/test.js
    new file:   dev2/test.js
    new file:   git
    new file:   log.txt
```

content of `.gitignore` file:

```
   hell.txt
   /dev1
```

After adding my whole content of the file, it is uploaded  even the file `hell.txt` as well as `dev1` folder too 
Also run the file in notepad, No issue of encoding
Also, I double checked this fact, first I included gitignore file then I included all the file.

Comment: add `hell.txt` and `dev1` one after other in .gitignore file

Comment: Yeah , I did that but still not working

Comment: the `/` before the `dev1` shouldn't be there, afterwards is ok

Comment: thanks a lot brother for your kind help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already staged dev1/test.js, that's why it's not being ignored. Use `git reset HEAD dev1/test.js` to unstage it.